# How can I pull post data from a select menu? option selected is linked to a postgresql database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ejs

```
<form method=post action="/download">   
<select name="select" id="select" class="custom-select w-25 p-1" size='<%%sqldata.length%>'>
    <option selected>Select Query</option>
    <%for (var i=0;i<sqldata.length;i++){%>
     <option value=<%=sqldata[i].description%>><%=sqldata[i].name%></option>
    <%}%>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</select>    
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm trying to use req.body.select to pull the data from the value selected by the user,it seems to stop when it hits a whitespace,what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "pull post data"

Comment: I'm trying to store the value of the select menu into req.body.select, but i'm only successful in getting the string value up till a whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given key `some key` the code will render something like

```
...
<option value=some key>some value</option>
...
```

Where, I assume, there should be rendered

```
...
<option value="some key">some value</option>
```

Notice the double quote (") marks.

P.S.: the code shown awckwardly renders a `<button>` inside the `<select>`

Comment: Deleted the extra button, don't know how that got there. Still having trouble with the incomplete data though, am i writing the EJS portion wrong? thanks for the reply.

Comment: Adding double quotes solved the problem, Thanks for the help!